# Find the range of values in a geometric progression for which $g_1< 0$ and $g_3> 4g_2 -3g_1$

Tags: contest-math

Here $g_1,g_2$ and $g_3$ are three successive terms of a Geometric Progression.

I assumed them to be $a/r, a$ and $ar$ and used $B^2 = A.C$ but proved futile...Any trick?

Comment: Geometric progression is denoted by GP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $g1=a $, $g2=ar $, $g3=ar^2$, we have $$a <0$$ and $$ar^2>4ar-3a$$ Therefore we can write $$r^2-4r+3<0$$ which has solution $$ 1 <r <3$$

Note that the possibility $a >0$ and $r <0$, assuming $g1=ar $, $g2=ar^2$, $g3=ar^3$, would lead to the same solution   $ 1 <r <3\, $, which in this case contradicts the assumption  $r <0$. So the solution above is the only possible one.

Comment: We could have $a>0$ and $r<0$ don't you think ?

Comment: No, assuming $g1=ar$, $g2=ar^2$, $g3=ar^3$ with $a>0$ and $r <0$, we get $ar^3>4ar^2-3ar$ and then again $r^2-4r+3<0$. This has solution $ 1 <r <3$, which contradicts the assumption  $r <0$.

Comment: Thus, this discussion should be part of your solution, don't you think ?

Comment: Right, I edited my answer to clarify this issue.